# Bring setq variable into a (let ...) context of a elisp function?

Tags: let-binding, local-variables, scope

I have written a function snippet that copies a paragraph to the `kill-ring`. I try to collect different point positions and corresponding line numbers:

- `bop` - begin of paragraph
- `blnum` - line umber of the paragraph begin
- `eop` - end of paragraph
- `elnum` - line number of the paragraph ending

...see below code

and store them in some variable via `setq`. I know that I'm using here a global variable context in a false way. What is the equivalent code using a local variables scope only?

To be clear, none of variables (`bop, eop, blnum, elnum`) will be used outside of the function context.

## CODE

```lisp
(defun my/copy-paragraph ()
  "Copy a paragraph to the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (backward-paragraph)
  (setq bop (point))
  (setq blnum (line-number-at-pos))
  (forward-paragraph)
  (setq elnum (line-number-at-pos))
  (setq eop (point))
  (kill-ring-save bop eop)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (forward-line)
  (message "Copy paragraph from '%s' line %d - %d to kill-ring "
           (buffer-name) blnum elnum))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't clear. What do you want the (lexical) scope of the variables to **be**? What code do you want to be inside the scope, and what code outside it? A wild guess is that you just want to use `let` in your function body. Bind variables, then use `setq` in the body to give them values at the appropriate places.

```lisp
(defun my/copy-paragraph ()
  "Copy a paragraph to the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (let (bop blnum elnum eop)
    (backward-paragraph)
    (setq bop    (point)
          blnum  (line-number-at-pos))
    (forward-paragraph)
    (setq elnum  (line-number-at-pos)
          eop    (point))
    (kill-ring-save bop eop)
    (line-beginning-position)
    (forward-line)
    (message "Copy paragraph from '%s' line %d - %d to kill-ring "
             (buffer-name) blnum elnum)))
```

But *you're not even using variables `bop` and `eop`* here, so presumably you want to use them somewhere else? It's not clear where, which is why the question as a whole isn't clear. What's the lexical scope for them - is it just this function? This function doesn't call anything that would conceivably use them, so I can't imagine what they're for or what their scope should be.

Comment: To be clear, none of them (`bop, eop, blnum, elnum`) will be used outside of the function context. As I understood from your code, a simple `(let ...)` declaration will change the variable scope using `(setq ...)`. My understanding was `setq` works always in global scope. The points `bop & eop` are used in `(kill-ring-save bop eop)` ..not clear what you meaning here?

Comment: Oh right, all of those var are used here. Yes, if a var is not declared to be global (e.g. via `defvar`) then let-binding a variable of that name creates a lexical binding, and `setq` within the `let` binds the variable to the `setq` value. From what you say you want, all you need is what I wrote: a `let` with `setq`s for its vars in the `let` body.